# tmux: Running 'new-window "vim somefile"' gives me strange colors

Tags: tmux

I use tmux with solarized colors (256), and it works fine, except when I hit the key I have binded to: `new-window "vim somefile"`.

It opens the new window with strange colors, probably like if I had less than 256 enabled.

Why could that be and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.  run tmux as

`tmux -2` (forces 256 colors)

In your tmux.config put

`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

In your vimrc put

`set t_Co=256`

`set term=screen-256color`

AND in your shell that tmux is running you'll have to put

`export TERM="screen-256color"`

My experience has been that it only works when you tell every single one of them to shut up and pretend they have 256 colors.  Otherwise one of them will think they know better and fall back to 16 or 8.

But if your force it make sure you actually *do* have 256 colors available in the terminal.  Otherwise you'll end up with some strange stuff.

It took me *way* too long to figure all of that out.

It got easier once I started building all three from source.

They are *riddled* with bugs in the older versions.

(apparently others have had success with "xterm-256color", but that did *not* work for me.  You're just going to have to try.)